# rank revealing decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I was reading a research publication where I came across this line. Please can anyone explain its meaning and how this decomposition can be done

"We employed a rank revealing decomposition of the matrix A in the form A=BC. This decomposition should be performed in such a way that B has minimum number of columns to make model reduction pursued hereafter most effective"

Comment: The [original paper](https://math.berkeley.edu/~mgu/MA273/Strong_RRQR.pdf) defining rank-revealing QR decomposition is fairly readable - have a go at that.

Comment: Does the above problem statement imply a QR decomposition

Comment: Also how to ensure this minimum number of columns ?